# change frames/iframes to just one page #aspclassic

Tags: asp-classic

How do I rewrite the following PHP code in Classic ASP?

```
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<section><?php echo include('content/'.$_GET['p'].'.php') ?></section></body>
```

If the url is http://foo.bar.com/admin.php?p=pages, then *content/pages.php* is shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with INCLUDE but you could use Server.Transfer instead, eg.

```
Server.Transfer "content/" & Request.Form("p") & ".asp"
```

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? I'm resulting that there are multiple possibilities?

Comment: @user1469734 you also have Server.Execute, you can read on both by quick Googling, but essentially those are your only options to dynamically include and execute other ASP files.

Answer (score 1):

Never trust what comes from the clientside (browser) as they can try to hack you.

Since it is not likely that "shdyhio3hlkehio.asp" or similar is a proper file, you should limit the options to your actual selection and also have a default file which is a "catch all other requests".

Combine that with Server Side Includes and you have your setup ready.

You should also check if the user actually requested a page -- if "p" is empty then show a default message.

Note the use of `LCase` in the "`Select Case`"-line and lowercase values in the `Case`-lines.
This is due to the face that the string comparison is case-sensitive, meaning "about" (lowercase "a") and "About" (uppercase "A") is not the same.

Eksemple:

```
<% If Request.QueryString("p") = "" Then %>

    no specific page was request, show a default message

<% Else %>

    <% Select Case LCase(Request.QueryString("p")) %>
    <% Case "content" %><!-- #include file="content.asp" -->
    <% Case "about" %><!-- #include file="about.asp" -->
    <% Case "contact" %><!-- #include file="contact.asp" -->
    <% Case Else %><!-- #include file="404.asp" -->
    <% End Select %>

<% End If %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  something like this

```
 <!--#include file="somefile.asp"-->
```

in your HTML file .